# What does a return statement do inside a setter?

Tags: javascript, expression, variable-assignment, getter-setter

I have the following code:

```
var o = {};
o.a = 1;

var _value = 1;
Object.defineProperty(o,"a",{
    set: function(value){
        _value = value + 1;
        console.log("log: ", value, _value);
        return _value;
    },
    get: function(){
        return _value;
    }
});
```

In the setter method, I increment `_value` by one before returning it. So if I set `o.a = 5`, I would expect the console to print `6` (even though I realize that returning a value from setter doesn't make sense, usually). However, as the following snippet shows, the console prints `5`:

```
> o.a = 5;
log: 5 6 // from console.log;
5 // return; why does it == value and not value + 1?
> o.a;
6
> var i = o.a = 5;
> i;
5
> o.a;
6
```

So my question is why does it return `5` and not `6`?

I hope this is not because I made some silly mistake in the code.

Comment: Like @Thilo said, return in setter doesn't work. you can put `return 100` instead of `return _value` in the setter, you won't get 100 but 5 only (the value assigned to `i`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets look at the [*simple assignment*](https://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1):

> #### [11.13.1 Simple Assignment ( = )](https://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1)
>
> The production *AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 3. Let *rval* be [GetValue](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(*rref*).

So `rval` is assigned the value that is going to be assigned to left hand side (`o.a`). In your case `5`.

> 4. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true: [...]
> 5. Call [PutValue](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2)(*lref*, *rval*).

This is where the value is assigned to the left hand side (`PutValue(o.a, 5)`). As you can see, nothing is done with whathever `PutValue` returns (it doesn't return anything).

> 6. Return *rval*.

It simple returns the value that was assigned, in your case `5`.

---

The assignment expression always returns the value that was assigned.

Comment: be careful with Proxies however. in a proxy definition  the return value from set() does have meaning - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set

Answer (score 13):

You cannot return anything from a property setter,  and are just getting the value of the assignment (which is `5` because you assigned `5`).

> what does return in a setter do?

Nothing. Better remove that `return` statement. At best it's ignored.

Answer (score 4):

The value of an assignment expression is always equal to the value being assigned:

```
var a;
console.log(a = 7); // logs 7
```

This is true no matter whether the thing you are assigning to is a variable, plain property, setter, read-only property, or whatever:

```
var a = {};
Object.defineProperty(a, "b", { value: 8, writable: false });
console.log(a.b = 9);  // logs 9
console.log(a.b);      // logs 8, because a.b is read-only
```

As you said yourself, a return value in a setter is meaningless, so when you used a return value in your setter, why did you expect it to actually do anything special? To answer your question *"What does a return statement do inside a setter?"* - Basically nothing. It evaluates the expression to the right of the `return` and then throws away the result.

Comment: This answer addresses both issues raised in the question, not just the explicit question.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on why you want to do this. I personally had a set of enums, but one of them had an edge case, and making an exception for the edge case would create an inconsistency in my API. I thought I'd fake it with a setter that returns values, but that does not work, as you've discovered.

A potential solution to this problem is the use a getter with a proxy. *It does mean you're not returning from a setter like you asked*, but the below code will show why that might just be what you actually need.

The problem I had: Capture a mouse button and return a friendly name. If it's 0-2, return one of: 'MouseClickLeft', 'MouseClickRight', 'MouseClickMiddle'. Else, return a dynamic number such as 'MouseClick4', 'MouseClick5', etc. Make it act like an enum to keep the API consistent with my other enums.

```js
const baseEnums = {
    0: 'MouseClickLeft',
    1: 'MouseClickRight',
    2: 'MouseClickMiddle',
};

const MouseButtonName = new Proxy(baseEnums, {
    get: function(target, name) {
        return target[name] || `MouseClick${name}`;
    }
});
```

Example outputs:

```js
MouseButtonName['0']; // 'MouseClickLeft'
MouseButtonName['1']; // 'MouseClickRight'
MouseButtonName['2']; // 'MouseClickMiddle'
MouseButtonName['3']; // 'MouseClick3'
MouseButtonName['5']; // 'MouseClick5'
```

I used numbers converted to strings above, but textual strings work the same way.